# Can we access Apple watch tracking data through a WEB/REST API?

Tags: rest, api, apple-watch, healthkit

I am planning to access the Apple watch tracking data(steps,sleep etc.) of a user through WEB/REST API on my webapp.

I can't find any doc on Apple site regarding this, Is it possible ?(plz provide reference in your answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/) is where you would access Apple Watch sensor capabilities. Since health data is sensitive, you would have to look through the documentation linked below and see what's accessible. You'll also have to ask for user permission and provide a privacy policy when submitting to the App Store. As for your web app counterpart, you can use transport mechanisms like URLSession and perhaps [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/).

- [HealthKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit)
- [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system)
- [CloudKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit)

Comment: So basically without an iOS app its not possible to get data from apple watch. Data flow is  like device -> your iOS app -> your webApp . Am i correct?. Can i access data directly from webapp just like fitbit ?

Comment: You can create a independent watchOS app without the iOS requirement. It depends on the type of data, as I mentioned you have to look at the HealthKit documentation.

Comment: i just want the basic data like steps,distance,sleep. And i want to get this data on my web portal.

Comment: Healthkit is the only option, you should have and iOS app which connects with Healthkit on your phone to get Apple Watch data through Apple Health